# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received Promise { <pending> }

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm getting this error while I'm trying to scrape `prnt.sc`, and I don't understand why.

I think `setInterval()` is giving me problems.

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received Promise {  }

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const select = require('puppeteer-select');

async function llamar() {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true
  });

  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    text += "https://prnt.sc/" + possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  console.log(text)


  const page = await browser.newPage();
  path = Math.random()
  await page.goto(text)
  const element = await select(page).getElement('button:contains(AGREE)');
  await element.click()
  await page.screenshot({
    path: path + '.jpg'
  })

  await browser.close();
}

setInterval(llamar(), 2000);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, in `setInterval`, you are supposed to give a function, not execute one.

`llamar()` is executing the function.

Try this:

```
setInterval(llamar, 2000);
```